# Get messages to DebugView

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

I need to write application that could create debug messages that could be displayed in [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx). For this purpose I'm using code:

```
int main ()
{
    OutputDebugString(L"hello");
    return 0;
}
```

But no messages are displayed in DebugViewer.

Where is problem?

Comment: Hard to answer. What is "DebugViewer"?

Comment: DebugView is an application that lets you monitor debug output http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx

Comment: Debug Viewer does not see the messages when you run application with IDE debugger (in which case debug output is shown by the IDE).

Comment: OK, I see. The program is actually called DebugView, FWIW.

Comment: OutputDebugString(L"hello");  can only be shown on DebugView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DebugView won't receive debug messages if there is already a debugger the receives them. If you run your process under the IDE's debugger, then it receives these messages. Either:

- View the debug messages in the IDE's window, or
- Run the process outside the debugger and view the messages in DebugView.